# is there any commercial apache server available other than xampp and wamp

Tags: php, android, apache, server

I am developing a tablet based android application and its back-end and api calls are done in php (slim lib) and mysql.

the app architecture is bellow.

there will be a local server machine in the building / room for handling api calls from android app through wifi network. all the data and media files uploaded /stored in the local machine. android app fetches the data/media files form server on demand via api calls.

Now am using xampp server for my test purpose and its work decently up to 10 devices . if the number of devices increases some devices lost the response from server or wait long time for response especially in file downloading from server to tab.

I have tested the app with real devices and commercial router. I need to improve the response speed from server and fast simultaneous file downloading.

Is there any commercial local apache server package available other than xampp and wampp.

Comment: try lighttpd instead of apache. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use EasyPHP. It is is one of the best contenders to Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Laragon
Easy Php
There are others, check out:
http://alternativeto.net

Comment: which one is fast and best in simultaneous request handling